# How do I get the parent context from within a component in glimmer?

Tags: javascript, components, glimmer.js

Let's say I have a simple component in glimmer with a list of items

```
<todo-list @items={{ items }}></todo-list>
```

template.hbs

```
<ul>
  {{#each @items key="@index" as |item|}}
    <li onclick={{ action clickme }}>{{ item }}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

component.ts

```
import Component, { tracked }  from '@glimmer/component';

export default class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
  }
  clickme() {
     // how do I access the parent context from here?
  }
}
```

Even if I pass in an action from the parent

```
<todo-list @items={{ items }} @rootclickme={{ rootclickme }}></todo-list>
```

updated, template.hbs

```
<ul>
  {{#each @items key="@index" as |item|}}
    <li onclick={{ action @rootclickme }}>{{ item }}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

in my outer component.ts

```
rootclickme () {
    // I don't have access to parent variables here either?
    // only what's within the scope of the function itself?         
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have a component with a list. When a list item is clicked, I want it to bubble up a click event to the top, so that the parent component can decide to hide the list and show a more detailed view for this selected item.

How do I go about doing this in glimmer? In react I'd be passing

**Note:** I'm not using full ember.js, just glimmer.js standalone

Comment: When you're binding the action in, it should be `@rootclickme={{action rootclickme }}`. Using the `action` helper ensures that the callback's `this` is bound to the proper component.

Comment: You also seem to have cut your post short? "In react I'd be passing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your comment that you only have access to what's in the function body, my suspicion is that the missing `action` helper when binding the action to the child component is making the callback lose its `this`.

To address it, bind it in like this:

```
<todo-list @items={{ items }} @rootclickme={{action rootclickme}}></todo-list>
```

I have made [an example playground](https://glimmer-playground.netlify.com/?app=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) that you can check out.

Answer (score 0):

Something I learned from React, that works in my Glimmer app as well: you can bind your functions in the constructor. That way, when you pass them around to different objects, they won't lose their context.

```
export default class WhateverRootComponent extends Component {
  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.rootClickMe = this.rootClickMe.bind(this)
  }
  rootClickMe() {
    console.log(this instanceof WhateverRootComponent)
  }
}
```

Now you can pass that function in directly as you were doing before, without using the extra `action` helper.

```
<!-- WhateverRootComponent template -->
<SomeChild @actionToTake={{ rootClickMe }} />
```

then...

```
<!-- SomeChild template -->
<button onclick={{ action @actionToTake }}> Click Me </button>
```

When clicked, the console will log `true` because the function still is being called in the parent class's context.